# If we have an equilateral triangle with a square inscribed in it, could we prove that the triangles we get are congruent?

Tags: geometry

[image]

(I forgot to add a last point. Let $X$ be the midpoint of $\overline{GF}$.)

> Could we prove that triangles $CGX$, $CFX$, $GAS$, and $FBE$ are all congruent?

Comment: Have you tried any of the standard methods used to show that triangles are congruent?

Comment: This is false: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/egthdpdt

Comment: (Your figure marks $F$ and $G$ as midpoints. I'm guessing this is your way of indicating what you're trying to prove, so I'll ignore the marks.) ...  Glue the two bottom triangles together to form a (necessarily-equilateral) triangle. Note that that triangle has an *altitude* equal to a side of the square, whereas the upper equilateral triangle has a *base* equal to a side of the square. What conclusion can you draw?

Comment: @Micah That doesn't follow the question, your diagram doesn't have a square.

Comment: @abk: You are correct that @ Micah's diagram doesn't have a square. However, it *does* have four congruent triangles. Therefore, ...

Comment: @Blue just because a diagram has one thing but not the other doesn't mean they're mutually exclusive. It would be more accurate to show a triangle w/square inscribed and show that it doesn't have four congruent triangles. I did do that though, and I found that the triangles aren't congruent.

Comment: @abk: *"just because a diagram has one thing but not the other doesn't mean they're mutually exclusive"* ... Not generally, no. In this case, however, the diagram offers a pretty convincing demonstration of the proposition that, *if the triangles are congruent, then the quadrilateral isn't a square* (and, thus, by contraposition, *if the quadrilateral is a square, then the triangles aren't congruent*) Be that as it may ... Since you have found for yourself that the triangles aren't congruent, you should post (and accept) an answer to that effect, to let others know no more answers are sought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$. As $C,G$ and $A$ are collinear, $C,X$ and $M$ are collinear and $\overline{GX}$ is parallel to $\overline{AM}$, $\triangle CXG$ must be similar to $\triangle CMA$. Hence, $\frac{GX}{XC}=\frac{AM}{MC}$. Then, observe that $XC=MC-2GX$ and, by Pythagoras', $MC=\sqrt{(2AM)^2-AM^2}=\sqrt{3}AM$.

Hence, $\frac{GX}{\sqrt{3}AM-2GX}=\frac{AM}{\sqrt{3}AM}$ and $GX=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}+2}AM$. Given that $\triangle CXG$ and $\triangle GDA$ are oriented the same way, if they were congruent, we would have $GX=AD=\frac{AM}{2}$ but this is not the case as $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}+2}\neq \frac12$. Hence the triangles are not congruent and furthermore, $G$ is not the midpoint of $AC$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, show that they're similar. Each triangle has one angle of 90°, one of 60°, and one of 30°. That makes them similar.

(More specifically, for GAS and FBE, the 60° angle is the one they share with the equilateral triangle ABC. For the other two, the 30° angle is half of the angle at C. And all of them have a right angle too.)

To show congruence, check that they have one side the same length. For example, the sides you've marked with one line are each the hypothenuse of one of these triangles. So, if you can show that they're the same size, you're finished!

Comment: ... or they would be, if the lines that are marked as the same length in the diagram were actually the same length. Whoops!